# How can i use my android library project in flutter project? is creating plugin for it is only way?

Tags: flutter, android-library

I am starting new project in flutter, this project will have some common features already developed in Android library project.
But I am trying to identify how to use my android library project in new flutter project

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a plugin to expose your native code to flutter using [FlutterMethodChannel](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)